# alternative to move the scrollbar to an element with with duration time and avoid using $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:element.offset().top})

Tags: javascript, angular

I currently have a project in `angular`, and I have not found a way to make a smooth animation where the `scrollbar` is moved to another element. I found an example where what I need is done but using `jquery`.

I like to have in my code the necessary libraries strictly, but I would be including `jquery` exclusively for this purpose only and it is what I do not want.

what is the equivalent of this code in `javascript` or `angular` and what is its equivalent to stop the transition at some point?

**Note:**

I am using this function of `jquery` because I have not found something that allows me to have a fluid animation and that allows me to define the duration of this animation

```js
  //scroll to #final with duration of 17 seconds
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#final").offset().top
  }, 17000, (data)=>{
    console.log(data)
  });
  //stop my animation after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(()=>{
    $('html, body').stop();
  },3000)
```

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

*{
 box-sizing:border-box !important;
}

#final{
  border:1px solid red;
}

.height500vh{
 height:500vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="height500vh"></div>
<div id="final">final</div>
```

Comment: I think a CSS animation will be enough for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Omkar76 I need to achieve this from programming

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can use [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
const finalElem = document.querySelector('#final');
finalElem.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"})
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but note that I use this function because it allows me to define the duration of this transition